# Disposing an IDisposable object stored in a public static field

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

If a class has an instance field that implements IDisposable then the containing class implements IDisposable and class that fields Dispose method from within its Dispose method.

```
public class A : IDisposable 
{
    public System.Drawing.Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        font.Dispose()
    }
}
```

(I know I didn't do the dispose pattern correctly, but for sample code should be good enough)

If the field is a static field though where should the call to the field's Dispose be?

```
public class B
{
    public static System.Drawing.Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
}
```

I could make class B implement IDisposable and have that call `font.Dispose` but if B.font is used again later on that would cause problems. As well as you'd have to remember that dispise accessing a static method you need to create an instance just to call Dispose.

I could also make a static Dispose method but then users have to remember to call Dispose and have to make sure they're the last user of it in the program.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static object", so the question is meaningless.

Comment: your question is general. try to specific it.

Comment: Woops, typed there. Thanks for the catch

Comment: In some cases you need to override that.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking now. Did you try the obvious approach of `A.font.Dispose()`? If not, why not?

Comment: Going to go for a complete rewrite of the question I think. Case of brain asking faster then i can think of how to ask

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea from the onset. What happens if you decide to use the reference after you've called `Dispose` (but forgot to reinitialize)? I hope you are not handing this code out for others to use.

Comment: That's somewhat the root of the question I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Static fields are initialised when the type is loaded.

Therefore it logically it makes sense to dispose the object assigned to the static field when the containing type is unloaded.

However, types are not unloaded. There may be some exotic complication here around AppDomains, but I suspect that doesn't apply in your case.

Therefore I wouldn't dispose the instance, otherwise you will have a publicly available instance of an object that is unfit for use.

Comment: I like the logic. Dispose only when the type is unloaded. Types are never unloaded. Therefore, don't dispose.

Comment: But still, if the static field is not `readonly`, when it is reassigned, it might be a good idea to dispose the old instance, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You dispose of it like any other object. It doesn't make a difference.   A static object is just an object that is available per class.  It's still an instance of something. Granted, you probably wouldn't want to do this since after you dispose of it someone can still access it and get a `ObjectDisposedException` exception.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Test.Instance)
        {

        }  

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    public class Test:IDisposable
    {
        public static Test Instance = new Test();
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
        }
    }
```

And the output is:

> Disposed

Per your updated example:

```
public class A
{
    public static System.Drawing.Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f));
}
```

You can just do `A.font.Dispose()` or `using(A.font)`

In general I think the idea is you really wouldn't have a public static disposable field since by making it static you imply it should be around for the lifetime of the application. If it has to be disposable you should could  make it lazy and make it be thread-safely re-initializable, otherwise accessing it after disposing will throw exceptions.  Or you can have a hook into your application end code and safely dispose of all static disposables there. You can register your disposable on start somewhere as well. Just an idea

Comment: Your first example doesn't make much sense to me. Can `Instance` field only be read once? Because after `using (Test.Instance) { ... }` the object is disposed (and therefore presumably no longer usable), so if someone says `Test.Instance` a second time they get a "broken" object that has already been disposed.

Comment: I was just answering what the original question was asking, not saying it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

If the field is static, then maybe the intention is to have it last for the complete duration of the application? Because then it will only need to be disposed of when the application shuts down. And that will happen one way or the other, by itself-

If you plan to reassign the static field to different `IDisposable` objects several times during the lifetime of the application, then of course you would want to dispose the old object when you reassign. Maybe you could use a property for that? Not that I have thought a lot about it, but something like:

```
// private - don't write to this field from outside the property setter
static Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f));

public static Font Font
{
  get
  {
    return font;
  }
  set
  {
    var oldFont = font;
    if (oldFont != null)
      oldFont.Dispose();
    font = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't dispose a static class because there is no instance of it

Comment: Note that no one is going to know to call `A.Dispose()`, because it simply isn't done.

Comment: Simply put, (1) `IDisposable` is meant for disposing *instances*, not whole classes.  While you could have a static `Dispose` that disposes every static member, (2) the semantics of `Dispose` are such that whatever you `Dispose` is now a useless husk, and should not be used for anything else.  Disposing a whole class?  Ehhh....

Comment: The question is not about disposing static class but static instance (of a regular class).