# Just how 'disposable' is ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

I principally follow the `IDisposable` pattern, and for most classes that is justified. But `ReaderWriterLockSlim` made me question the viability of applying such pattern. All `ReaderWriterLockSlim.Dispose` does is close some event handles. So how important is it to `Dispose` such class with so few resources? In this case, I really wouldn't mind if the GC had to wait another round for the finalizers of the unmanaged resources to finish.

The consequence for applying the `IDisposable` pattern is considerable however, every class that uses a disposable class now has to implement `IDisposable` too. In my particular case, I am implementing a wrapper for `HashSet`. I don't particularly expect the requirement to dispose such object because, accidently, it uses a synchronizer which does.

Are there any reasons not to violate the disposable pattern in this case? While I am eager to, I wouldn't do so in practice, because violating consistency is much worse.

Comment: Your problem is that your using a non-static lock that has the same lifetime as your objects?

Comment: @NathanCooper - Roughly, yes. Instantiating a lock for each read/write operation is not really efficient either. I could use `Monitor`, but I worry for lock convoys.

Comment: so you're reading or writing to something and it is not static? So it's some resource for each instance.

Comment: Yes, currently the class consists of `HashSet(T)` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim` where the latter synchronizes any operation.

Comment: It is pretty rare to ever *need* to dispose such an object, it tends to live for the life of the program.  Don't waste any time disposing it a millisecond before your program terminates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with unmanaged OS handles is that [handles come from a limited supply.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx) The GC is not aware of this.

The pure memory consumption of a handle is not that big. Nothing more than an object in kernel memory and probably hash table entry somewhere.

You are right in that it is not enough to say: "You must *always* dispose all disposable objects". That rule is too simple. [For example the `Task` class does not need to be disposed.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx) If you know what you are doing you can take a looser stance regarding disposal. Be aware that not all team members might understand this point (now you can leave a link to this answer in the source code...).

If you are sure that you will not leak a lot of handles you can safely do this. Be aware that under edge conditions (load, bugs, ...) you might leak more that you anticipated causing production issues.

Answer (score 1):

If this field is `static` [you don't need to dispose of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032941/disposing-an-idisposable-object-stored-in-a-public-static-field), it will (righty) have the same lifetime as your application. I see it's not, lets move on.

The correct way to handle an IDisposable is to dispose of it. I think we need a good reason not do this.

**Use another lock:**

I think the best thing to do is to use `Monitor` or another lock, which will have the bonus of simplifying your code as well. `ConcurrentDictionary` and other framework classes seem to take this approach.

You are worried about lock conveys, but I'm not sure this is even solved by `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, the only real solution is to hold less locks and hold them for less time.

**Don't dispose:**

This needs a justification. Can you demonstrate needed performance benefits here?

If you have a few of these objects that are long lived, fine, not all disposables are equally weighty (it's not like your leaving a word document open), you will probably get away with it. As it has been pointed out, what is the point of disposing of all this milliseconds before the application closes anyway. I believe the destructor of an IDisposable is in meant to handle situations where the object is not disposed, although you can't be sure when or even if this is called.

If you have a long lived applciation with lots of short-lived usages of this class, however, you may run into trouble. You are baking in your assumptions about the use of your code, just be aware.

Comment: With 'destructor', do you mean a finalizer? Thats probably not even necessary because the unmanaged resources will have finalizers themselves, so they will do what the dispose method would have invoked.

I understand that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` only offers a benefit with many dense read operations, right? `Monitor` probably wouldn't underperform for what I'm trying to do, but I want to be safe in the future.

Comment: C# destructors are .NET finalizers. I did point out that they do it for themselves,... I'm removing that paragraph. Making the decision to not dispose will bake in some of your assumptions (it will make it trickier to write an application with a long life that uses tons of these objects in a short-lived fashion. As usr points out it may eat up all the handles). I would make that decision according to actual need, rather than future proofing.

Comment: Yes I figured there was some ambiguity somewhere. Simply put, the worst thing that can happen is that the GC must postpone cleanup for the unmanaged resources because it has to run their finalizers. As for baking in assumptions, I think I can get away with it this time, as Hans explained that this kind of class is not really conventional to instantiate at just any time, let alone a multitude of times.

Comment: @toplel32  Cool (we're always baking in assumptions, it's called coding, I sounded a bit dramatic there). I think that's sensible. I can't imagine the future code that would go `while(1) { var foo = new toplelResourceReader(); }` anyway.